# Como actualizar textarea desde PHP sin esperar al success de post en JQuery

Tags: php, html, jquery, post

veréis, tengo un formulario que envío por post a través de JQuery ya que no quiero que me actualice la página. Hasta ahí todo correcto. El problema viene cuando quiero actualizar un textarea de mi formulario antes de que acabe la petición, ya que realiza todos los cambios que mi código hace cuando termina la petición.

El código de la petición es el siguiente:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function() {
    var post_data = $('#formulario').serialize();
    $.post('/escandallar', post_data, function(data) {
        $('#log').append(data + '\n');
    });
});
```

He probado de hacer echo en el código PHP, pero me lo sigue actualizando cuando ya ha terminado la petición.

Gracias de antemano y un saludo.

Edit: el text area es un log dónde aparece todo lo que se va haciendo durante la petición, por esto necesito actualizarlo durante la petición, aunque después de error, que el usuario pueda ver el proceso que se ha completado correctamente.

Comment: Lo que dices es contradictorio. Las peticiones Ajax son asíncronas y por tanto no puedes usar los datos que dependen de su respuesta fuera del success precisamente porque podrías estar intentando usar `data` (lo que devuelve el servidor) antes de que la petición haya sido procesada y devuelta. El planteamiento es confuso. Para ser simples: si necesitas hacer algo con `data` tienes que hacerlo dentro del success, si quieres hacer algo que no tenga **nada que ver con la petición (que esta haya terminado, los datos devueltos, etc)**, puedes hacerlo donde quieras.

Comment: Tu Edit arroja más confusión todavía. ¿Qué significa: *«aunque después de error, que el usuario pueda ver el proceso que se ha completado correctamente»*? Si en la petición ocurre algún error (en el servidor) y quieres mostrarlo en el cliente (textarea), lo que tienes que hacer es mandar un mensaje de error desde el servidor y mostrarlo en el cliente (textarea). Pero como ya dije en el anterior comentario, dado que esa información depende de lo que ocurra en el servidor, no puedes hacerlo fuera del success, porque hasta que la petición no termine no podrás saber qué ocurrió en el servidor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `shorthand` que ocupas no te va a permitir conocer todos los estados de la petición a menos que uses la petición `ajax`  en su forma original.

Verás, hay tres estados que puedes conocer en una petición `ajax`:

1. `beforeSend`: Se ejecuta antes de enviar la petición al servidor
2. `success`: Cuando el servidor responde, esta función se ejecuta
3. `complete`: Se ejecuta cuando la petición finaliza después de haber llamado `success` y `error`, es decir, cuando la peitición finaliza completamente ya sea con un error o no.

Puedes leer más acerca de esto [aquí](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Ahora bien, para actualizar tu formulario antes de que acabe tu petición hay dos trucos:

1. Que desde tu archivo php mandes a llamar con un `parent` en javascript una función que tengas desde tu código javascript origen.
2. Que te apoyes en la función `beforeSend` de `AJAX` para que lo hagas más bien antes de enviar la petición al servidor.

Como ejemplo del número 1, supongamos que tienes este código javascript:

```
<script>
    function mifuncion() {alert(1);}
   //... aquí tendrías que poner tu petición ajax que va al archivo php
</script>
```

Entonces, haces una petición `AJAX` desde este punto a un archivo `.php` cualquiera. Dentro de ese archivo que llamaremos ejemplo.php haremos lo siguiente:

```
<?php
echo "parent.mifuncion();";
echo "he finalizado después de ejecutar el echo de arriba";
```

Ahora bien, explicando la sugerencia #2, las cosas se vuelven más sencillas cuando te apoyas en la función callback `beforeSend`, ya que solo harías lo siguiente:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "tuarchivo.php",
    data : {

    },
    beforeSend : function()  {
       //aquí va todo lo que quieras hacer antes de mandar tu petición
    },
    success : function(data) {
        //aquí el servidor ya te respondió pudiendo recibir esa respuesta con el parámetro data
    },
    complete : function() {
        //aquí finaliza o bien o mal tu petición
    }
});
```

Espero haberte dado ejemplos claros sobre lo que necesites y cómo podrías mejorarlo. También como más referencias, te recomiendo leer el estatus de una petición ajax sabiendo su porcentaje de carga del 1 al 100, tal vez también esto pueda servirte en un futuro para decidir qué hacer en cualquier momento del flujo de carga de la petición al servidor.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690740/how-to-show-loading-status-in-percentage-for-ajax-response
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21648356/jquery-ajax-beforesend-and-success-error-complete